# Adding two layers to a fusion table, Identify a point within a polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I currently have two tables, one is a [polygon layer](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S462626Yxwh) and the other is a list of events [points](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S462628F9Se).

I was curious if it would be possible to display both of these tables on the same map. My final goal is to display them on a webpage, that will allow the user to select a polygon and then have all of the points within the selected polygon show up on a dashboard and I'm not sure if that is possible.

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy to do from a webpage,  basically you just need to create multiple fusion table layers, and add them to your map, something like this should work nicely (I did notice that your layers are currently private, if you want them to be accessible from a web page, they must be marked as public):

```
//Create the map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
{
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}); 

//Add the first fusion table layer
var layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: 'Address',
    from: **Layer1ID**
    },
    map: map
});

//Add the second fusion table layer
var layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
    select: 'Address',
    from: **Layer2ID**
    },
    map: map
});
```

Comment: Thank for for the reply! This is just what I was looking for. I have updated my tables to public. My final product was intended to be a website, so this is excellent for me. For the top, would I embed that in the HTML code??

Also, for the above polygon layer linked, would the "S462819X5kB" from the URL be the Layer ID?

Comment: For the table ID,  you need to go into the fusion tables view for each,  from the File menu, choose About,  and the value you are looking for is the Numeric ID.  For your polygon layer, it is  3608398

Answer (score 0):

Re: *"allow the user to select a polygon and then have all of the points within the selected polygon show up on a dashboard and I'm not sure if that is possible."*  The Fusion Table SQL API has an ST_INTERSECTS operator which would almost accomplish this.  But it only works for Circles and Rectangles.  Not for Polygons.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this! I should have mentioned it was a square/rectangle layer. The inner-GIS lingo coming out of me there.